# Running 'jekyll serve' on cloud foundry

Tags: ruby, jekyll, cloud-foundry

I'd like to serve a jekyll site from a deployed app on cloud foundry using `bundle exec jekyll serve`, but I get an error when the app tries to start.

I'm testing with a new jekyll 3.3.0 site, I have just added exclude `vendor` to the _config.yml.

I'm trying this manifest.yml file with the standard ruby buildpack:

```
---
applications:
- name: cf-jekyll-serve
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  path: .
  command: bundle exec jekyll serve --port $PORT
```

The application fails to start, with the log message:

```
jekyll 3.3.0 | Error:  No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/vcap/app/ld_library_path/libreadline.so.5
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the ruby buildpack creates a `ld_library_path` dir in the build directory, which contains a broken symbolic link to `/home/vcap/app/ld_library_path/libreadline.so.5`. When jekyll runs, it tries to copy everything in the build dir to the _site dir, so the error was reporting this missing symbolic link. To fix I added `ld_library_path` to the jekyll config excludes.